# How to map JSON response to props using React-Redux-Saga?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

I'm new to React and I'm trying to build a simple single page app that gets some data from a JSON and displays it as part of a component. I'm using Redux/Saga.

Said JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "objA": {
  "description": description,
  "name": name,
  "status": status
},
{
  "objB": {
  "description": description,
  "name": name,
  "status": status
}
```

Now, when I make the request, in the Network tab (console) I can see I get it okay, but I can't seem to map it to the props of my component. Here is some of my code.

container/competitionsSection.js

```
class CompetitionsSection extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(getCompetitionsAction());
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.competitions, 'Competitions'); //returns undefined
    return (<div> </div>)
  }
}

CompetitionsSection.propTypes = {

}; 

const mapStateToProps = ({ competitions }) => ({
  competitions: competitions,
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps)(CompetitionsSection);
```

sagas/competitionsSaga.js

```
export function* competitionsSaga({ }) {
  try {
    const competitions = yield call(getCompetitions);
    yield put({ type: types.GET_COMPETITIONS_SUCCESS, competitions })
  } catch (error) {
    yield put({ type: 'SEARCH_MEDIA_ERROR', error });
  }
}
```

actions/competitionsAction.js

```
export const getCompetitionsAction = () => ({
  type: types.GET_COMPETITIONS_SUCCESS
});
```

reducers/competitionsReducer.js

```
export default function (state = initialState.competitions, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.GET_COMPETITIONS_SUCCESS:
      return [...state, action.competitions];
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

api/api.js (here I think I have the problem)

```
export const getCompetitions = () => {
  const GET_COMPETITIONS_ENDPOINT = /endpoint

  return fetch(GET_COMPETITIONS_ENDPOINT)
  .then(response => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(json => {
     console.log(json); //response in the objA {..}, objB {..} format
     return json.data.map(({ name, description, status }) => ({
         name,
         description,
         status
      }));
  });
};
```

I'm following [Scotch's tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-media-library-with-react-redux-and-redux-saga-part-2). Any help will be appreciated it. Thanks!

Comment: Show us your reducer :-)

Comment: @andresmijares25 Just added it

Comment: Awesome, on ur mapStateToPropsnu are pulling a competitors funcion, however, ur reducer has no name, name ur reducer function to competitions.

Comment: @andresmijares25 did it and no change. But I console logged on the reducer and it checked 3 times, just once with the action type I needed. Is that okay? :/

Comment: Yes! It's hard to tell what is the problem here, try to put ur code in a fiddle, i will help :-)